# Freeness of completed homology over universal deformation ring

Tags: rt.representation-theory, deformation-theory, galois-representations, geometric-representation-theory, p-adic

In Theorem 7.4 of the paper "patching and the $p$-adic Langlands program for $\mathrm{GL}2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$" ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.06902.pdf)), it is proved that in the minimally ramified  case, the completed homology of given level is the completed tensor of the dual family of Banach representation (denoted as $\tilde{P}$) with the Galois representation. It seems the result should be valid as long as the local deformation rings outside $p$ are smooth. (Is it right?) It is remarked that the method does not apply beyond the locally formally smooth case.

My question is: in which generality can one get such result, by putting additional restrictions on the deformation problems outside $p$? For example can one (under reasonable assumptions) look at one irreducible component of the universal deformation space and prove such free rank one result of the corresponding quotient space of completed homology with appropriate level?